# Passing prop via map method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to map through an array to output a bunch of components.

The bit I'm having difficulty with is passing a function through as a prop - it looks something like this:

```
const myFunction = () => {
console.log("Got a click!")
}

const components = myArray.map(arrayItem => {
return <MyComponent clickHandler={myFunction}/>
});
```

... but I can't access myFunction from map. I know I could use context, but how would I achieve this with props?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't access myFunction from map"?

Comment: If the `myFunction` is in scope, then you can use it just fine in `.map`. Please provide more context

Answer (score -1):

```
const myFunction1 = () => {
console.log("Got a click!")
}

const myFunction2 = () => {
console.log("Got a click!")
}

const myArray = [myFunction1, myFunction2];

const components = myArray.map(arrayItem => {
    return <MyComponent clickHandler={arrayItem}/>
});
```

You have an array of functions and you want to add clickhandlers for your components where you make use of these functions, and these React components are stored in the new array `components`. is this what you are trying to do?

And if you want to pass this array (which has all these functions), pass it via props.

**Parent component**

```
const myFunction1 = () => {
console.log("Got a click!")
}

const myFunction2 = () => {
console.log("Got a click!")
}

const myArray = [myFunction1, myFunction2];

<Child passedArray = {myArray} />
```

**Child component**

```
const myArray = props.passedArray;

const components = myArray.map(arrayItem => {
    return <MyComponent clickHandler={arrayItem}/>
});
```

Comment: In the OP's question `myArray` and `arrayItem` don't have anything to do with the prop, or the passed function. There's currently nothing wrong with the OP's code and they should provide more information.

Comment: there may not be a syntactical problem with his code, but i guess he is trying to achive something similar to my answer.

Comment: Sure, but that's an assumption. Until the OP updates their question we'll never know